# Getting all the certificates in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-desktop

I'm trying to build a basic uwp app that is capable of searching and relocating certificates.

When I invoke

```
var all = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync();
var z = all.Count;// z = 0
```

z is always 0. Although I think that it should return all the certificates on the computer that are yet not expired ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificatestores.findallasync#Windows_Security_Cryptography_Certificates_CertificateStores_FindAllAsync))

I already added following capabilities to the app manifest:

`<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
<uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />`

from the namespaces `xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"` and `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"`

What am I missing?

Comment: I have tested with your code, but I can not reproduce your issue . I also tested with [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserCertificateStore), and it works too.